# How to add styling to laravel email notification

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

I am sending email notification in laravel app, But am using view instaed, but the style are not applying to the email. My style is located at head section of the html.

Answer (score 0):

can you edit config/mail.php and give a new path

```
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/admin/mail/style'),
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but am not using markdown. I have a custom view. But nevertheless i will try it.